# Checkbox value showing as `on` when unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

```
    <label for="filterByRcd">
      No GUI / Hi-Performance Mode
      <input type="checkbox" id="skipDraw" checked="checked">
    </label>
```

[image]

We can see it in the `Elements` section of `chrome`:

[image]

Here is the backend code translating to javascript variables:

```
_getSkipDraw() {
  let d = typeof this._skipDrawInput != "undefined" ? this._skipDrawInput.value == "on" : false
  return d
}
```

Surprisingly however the value of `this._skipDrawInput` is showing as **on** (and Therefore the variable `d` is being set to `true` instead of `false`):

[image]

Why is there this disconnect between the `value` and the actual state of the `checkbox`?  Is there a different property needed to read its value?

Wh

Comment: only checkboxes which are currently checked are submitted to the server, and the reported value is the value of the value attribute. If the value is not otherwise specified, it is the string on by default https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: (face palm) ..  ..

Comment: You have `name` missing too

Comment: Usually do not _need_ `name` but looks like here might be the case if using `getElementsByName()` .   This is getting to be fair amount of work since also likely need ajax to update backend behavior.